# Is it possible to turn my complicated for loop into nested list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm working on a CSV that lists a bunch of songs, and now need to merge duplicate songs.

1. `masterList` is a tuple of lists. Each list is a song.
2. `songsMatch()` inputs two songs and outputs `False` or `True` depending on whether or not the 2 songs match.

I was able to use list comprehension to create a list of *pairs* of matching songs, as follows:

```
matches = [
  [masterList[index1], masterList(index2)] 
  for index1 in range(1, len(masterList)-2) 
  for index2 in range(index1+1, len(masterList)) 
  if songsMatch(masterList[index1], masterList[index2])
]
```

However, I want all matching songs to be in the same sub-list, as opposed to creating three sub-lists. Here's some code I made that does more or less what I want:

```
matches = []
for index1 in range(1, len(masterList) - 2):
    newList = [masterList[index1]]
    for index2 in range(index1+1, len(masterList)):
        if songsMatch(masterList[index1], masterList[index2]):
            newList.append(masterList[index2])
    if len(newList) != 1:
        matches.append(newList)
```

This code more or less works. (If a song shows up 3 times, this still outputs a three-item list and then a two-item list, which isn't great but I think I can work with that.) However, I wanted to see if I could use nested list comprehension to rewrite this. Any ideas?

I tried something like this:

```
matches=[[masterList[index2] for index2 in range(index1+1, len(masterList)) if songsMatch(masterList[index1], masterList[index2])] for index1 in range(1, len(masterList)-2)]
```

When I printed out `matches`, I noticed that there were lots of empty lists in my output, and I'm not sure why. Those are easy to deal with. However, the main thing I want is to make sure that if my inputs have If I were to use this code, I also would want to make sure that each sublist starts out with `masterList[index1]`, meaning that both matching songs would be in the output as opposed to just the second one.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the input and desired output, rather than just _describing_ them?

Comment: Isn't this basically just [`itertools.combination()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, this would be the list comprehension.

```
matches = [
  (masterList[index1], masterList[index2]) 
  for index1 in range(1, len(masterList)-2) 
  for index2 in range(index1+1, len(masterList)) 
  if songsMatch(masterList[index1], masterList[index2])
]
```

For nested loops in list comprehensions, your loops go from left to right, such that the leftmost loop is the outermost one and rightmost is the innermost one.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This code works for my initial purpose, which was to output _pairs_ of songs. In fact, I might use something like this. However, I'm looking for each list in my output to contain all versions of the duplicated song. Meaning, if Yesterday by the Beatles shows up 3 times in `masterList`, there should be a list of 3 songs all called "Yesterday" as opposed to 3 lists each of 2 songs called "Yesterday." Hope this makes sense, and if it doesn't, I'll probably edit my main post with an example since it seems I wasn't clear to most people.

Comment: Is the `Yesterday` output of your `songsMatch` function? Also, if you don't need a list of two, i.e. need a dynamic list, then we'll need to tweak the logic.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Lie Ryan above, the above code is just:

```
matches = [(song1, song2) 
           for song1, song2 in itertools.combination(masterList, 2)
           if songsMatch(song1, song2)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to identify the first song of each duplicate group (i.e. those with no previous match) and build groups from these songs with the subsequent ones that are duplicates.  Removing the duplicates from the next iteration ensures that sub-groups will not create unwanted matches.

*Note: I'm using a temporary list `sl` in the comprehension but, if you don't need the duplicates to remain in the masterList, you can work directly on it*

```
matches = [ [song]+[sl.pop(j) for j in dups[::-1]]
            for sl in [masterList.copy()]
            for i,song in enumerate(sl,1)
            for dups in [[j for j,s in enumerate(sl[i:],i) 
                            if songsMatch(s,song)]]
            if dups]
```

I'm not sure why you need this to be in a comprehension though. A more efficient algorithm would be to build the list of matching groups by comparing only one of the already matched song for each of the current groups (i.e. leveraging [transitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation)):

```
matches    = []

for song in masterList:
    for group in matches:
        if songsMatch(group[0],song): # only matching 1st of group
            group.append(song)        # is enough to establish membership 
            break
    else:
        matches.append([song])        # no-match starts new group

matches = [group for group in matches if len(group)>1]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I think this is the answer I'll use. Just one more question: why is there an `else` block not on the same indent level as an `if` block? I'm just confused if that's a syntax error or not, since the code seems to work fine.

Comment: The `else:` belongs to the `for group in matches:` loop.  It is executed when the loop is NOT broken by a `break` statement.  In this case when no match is found.